# ActionController::ParameterMissing at /posts param is missing or the value is empty: post on rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm facing an issue with params parameters. I'm following the rails guide in order to implement comments in my app, but when I try to post a comment I receive the error:

`ActionController::ParameterMissing at /posts param is missing or the value is empty: post`

This is the code in the controller which will raise the error

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text).tap do |post_params|
        post_params.require(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

here is the create method linked to post_params method

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if  @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new' 
    end   
end
```

and this is the view where i call form_with

```
<h1>My post</h1>

<p><%= @post.title%></p>
<p><%= @post.text%></p> 
<h2>Add a comment</h2>
<%= form_with(model: [@post, @post.comments.build], url: post_path, local: true) do |form|%>
    <p>
        <%= form.label :body%><br>
        <%= form.text_field :commenter%>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= form.label :body%>
        <%= form.text_area :body%>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= form.submit%>
    </p>
<% end%>
<p><%= link_to "edit", edit_post_path %></p>
```

Comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    private 

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

The routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  resources :comments
  root 'home#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `url: post_path` from your `form_with`.

`form_with` will be able to correctly route the form with only `[@post, @post.comments.build]`.  This should route to `post_comments_path`, but you are overriding this to `post_path`.  When the form is submitted `posts#create` is being called, and  `params.require(:post)` is throwing the error because there is no `post` key in the params object.

The `post_comments_path` will route to `comments#create` which should work as expected. You can add `url: post_comments_path` to be explicit.

**Update:**

The `NoMethodError` is caused by the lack of nested routes.  Currently, the routing for comments is based around `/comments/:id` routes and generating `comment_path` helpers.

We can use [nested routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) to better define our relations and make our controller actions a bit cleaner. We want to update `routes.rb` to read:

(you should also have your [root route](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root) at the top of the routes file)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

With the comments nested inside the posts block Rails will create nested routes akin to `posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id` and `post_comments_path`.

Comment: the things is when I remove ```url: post_path``` i got this error ```NoMethodError at /posts/1
undefined method `post_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f6a64c31420>:0x00007f6a812d5d28>
Did you mean?  posts_path ```

Comment: and when I put ```url: post_comments_path```  I got the same error, it's weird

Comment: actually when i put ```url: post_comments_path``` i got this namerror sorry ```NameError at /posts/1
undefined local variable or method `post_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f6a64c31420>:0x00007f6a803ed4a0>
Did you mean?  posts_path```

Comment: Can you add your routes file to the question? Do you the comments resources nested inside the posts?

Comment: i posted the routes.rb, i haven't nested the comments resources inside the posts, how do i do that?

Comment: @loba I updated my answer with information and references for updating your app to use nested resources.